# Properties declared in tableViewCellController cannot be accessed in tableViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode6

I declared three UITextView properties in my tableViewCellController.h.I linked them to the story board and assigned my prototype cell class to my tableViewCellController.

```
@interface RankingsTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextView *playerRank;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextView *playerName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextView *playerPoints;


@end
```

When I try to make them display text in my tableViewController.m, I cannot access these UITextView properties. I am doing this in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath
```

I have already imported tableViewCellController.h in tableViewController.m

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is register your NIB in the viewDidLoad method and use it in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Something like this:

in viewDidLoad:

```
NSString *myIdentifier = @"itemCellIdentifier";
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"itemCellNibName" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:myIdentifier];
```

The cell identifier should be set from the IB in UITableViewCell's properties:
[image: cell identifier]

Also in IB, the class name of this UITableViewCell should be set to RankingsTableViewCell. Something like below (replace it with SwipeableCell):

[image]

Then in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
-(RankingsTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
     static NSString *myIdentifier = @"itemCellIdentifier";

     RankingsTableViewCell *cell = (itemCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myIdentifier];
     cell.playerRank.text = @"rank"; //accessing properties
     return cell;
}
```

And that's it. 
I have not ran this particular code-snippet and the images are gathered from Google. But this should get your job done.

Comment: @ShawnClarke You're most welcome friend. Please mark it as the correct answer and up-vote too if possible. Thanks.

Comment: I marked it as the right answer but sorry i can't vote up at the moment cuz i dont have enough reputation